# In Java, is it OK to require classes that implement an interface to inherit from a specific base class?

Tags: java, casting

Quick style question:

I have a Java interface that defines functions that must be implemented by classes in a particular hierarchy, all descended from a specific base class.

There are contexts where I will be dealing with these classes through a pointer to the interface, but I need a pointer to the base class instead.

Example:

```
public class Base {}

public interface ChildRequirements {
    Base asBase();
}

public class Child extends Base implements ChildRequirements {
    Base asBase() { return this; }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public void doSomething(Base base) { }

    public void doSomethingElse(ChildRequirements creqt) {
        doSomething(creqt.asBase());
    }
}
```

Is this bad form? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Should I just cast creqt as Base and ignore the warnings?

Comment: No, `ChildRequirements` are only applicable to certain subclasses of the base class

Comment: Ah, okay. That's not clear from the question.

Comment: OK, not quite clear.  Are all objects that implement `ChildRequirements` also instances of `Base` (or a subclass thereof)?  Do all objects that are instances of `Base` (or a subclass thereof) implement `ChildRequirements`?  It seems to me like one of these should be a subtype of the other; or maybe they're actually just one `abstract` class.

Comment: "but I need a pointer to the base class instead".  What does this mean? If child extends base,  ya'll got a pointer to the base class if ya'll got one to the subclass. right?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a Java interface that defines functions that must be implemented by classes in a particular hierarchy, all descended from a specific base class.

Then it isn't an interface, it's an abstract base class. Get rid of `ChildRequirements` and instead have `Base` define the requirements and mark it `abstract`:

```
abstract public class Base {
    // ...required methods here, `abstract` if you don't have a
    // base implementation...
}

public class Child extends Base {
    // ...implements any `abstract` methods...
}

public class SomeClass {
    public void doSomething(Base base) { }

    public void doSomethingElse(Base creqt) {
        doSomething(creqt);
    }
}
```

But whenever possible, program to interfaces, not abstract classes.

Comment: The functions in question are only applicable to `Child`, so it wouldn't be appropriate to put them in `Base`. I'm probably overkilling, but there are many `Child` classes that have very repetitive copy-paste type stuff in them. I was trying to use the interface to make sure that the Child classes implement all the necessary functions... so perhaps I should do `public abstract Class AbstractChild extends Base` instead

Comment: @JimBurnell - You've said *"...all descended from a specific base class..."*. That means you need an abstract base class. It's fine if the methods you need are on `Child` (though it makes me wonder what `doSomething` could possibly do with `Base`). Java's type system is nominal (not structural), so requiring all of these to be subclasses of `Base` is feasible. But again: Whenever possible, program to interfaces, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference between your typing and just using interfaces and ol'regular inheritance. Your `return this` in the `Child` class seems to suggest you expect it to be a subtype of Base.  The way the interfaces are structured it seems like you are actually expressing an is-a relationship between `Base` and `ChildRequirements`, but decorating the super class.

Alternate typing:

```
//Straight-forware inheritance
public interface Base {
    
}

interface ChildRequirements extends Base{
    Base asBase();//return the super
}

class Child implements ChildRequirements {
    public Base asBase() { return this;}
}

class SomeClass {

    public void doSomething(Base base) { }

    public void doSomethingElse(ChildRequirements creqt) {
            doSomething(creqt.asBase());
    }
    

}
```